# Add text message entry into native messaging application in Android

Tags: android, sendmessage, smsmanager

In my application I am trying to send a text message with the following code and it's working fine. But when I check the native messaging application the message that i have sent from my application is not in the native messaging application. Am I missing something or is their any other code that I have to write, so that the text that I'll send from the application also get's updated in the native messaging application. The code that I am using is:

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null, message, null, null);
```

Please let me know how can I create an entry in the native messaging application of this message.

Thanks..